# Returning Top Customers by Territory For Each of the Last 4 Years and Summing Them SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Forgive me for the long title, but that is succinctly as I could put this problem. I have a table that contains sales data by sale as well as the sales date, territory, customer info etc for each sale. I want to return the top 10 customers in each territory for each of the last 4 years by sales value. If the customer shows up on multiple years top tens, it should sum the Total value of those years together and order by the total value. Therefore, if all top 10 customers were the same for all 4 years, I would only have 10 results. If if all top 10 customers were different for all 4 years, I would have 40 results. I want the query to read in today's date, so I don't have to update the years I am searching for each New Year. I am having trouble with even where to begin, and yes I am new to SQL.

The table is "Bookings". I have put the field types and some sample data below:

```
[BKS_BookDate] (datetime), [BKS_TerritoryCodes] (nvarchar(255)), [BKS_CUS_RecordID]  (uniqueidentifier), [BKS_BookAmt] (money).
```

Sample data:

BKS_BookDate    BKS_TerritoryCodes  BKS_CUS_RecordID    BKS_BookAmt

```
'2006-09-07 17:00:00.000' 'MF - USA'    'EF928A2E-1A71-4231-BFA9-0B1D2E903469'  '1190.00'

'2006-09-15 12:45:00.000'   'TT - South'    '68BAFD37-59F5-4985-8F3E-E440E3A0C3EE'  '1716.00'

'2006-09-15 12:45:00.000'   'TT - South'    '68BAFD37-59F5-4985-8F3E-E440E3A0C3EE' '864.00'

'2006-09-15 12:45:00.000'   'TT - South'    '68BAFD37-59F5-4985-8F3E-E440E3A0C3EE'  '822.00'

'2006-09-15 12:45:00.000'   'TT - South'    '68BAFD37-59F5-4985-8F3E-E440E3A0C3EE'   '760.00'

'2006-09-15 12:45:00.000'   'TT - South'    '68BAFD37-59F5-4985-8F3E-E440E3A0C3EE'  '0.00'
```

Update #3
With Mihir's help I have made the following changes:

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @Today         Date
        ,@LastSales     Int

Select   @Today = Getdate()
        ---- Last 4 year including current year, if excluding current year then use -4
        ,@LastSales = Datepart(Year, Dateadd(Year, -3, @Today))


;With Sales_CTE As
(
    Select   s.*
,Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.BKS_TerritoryCodes 
Order By s.BKS_TerritoryCodes,s.SaleYear,s.Amount Desc) As TopSales
    From    (
            Select   b.BKS_TerritoryCodes
                    ,Datepart(Year, b.BKS_BookDate) As SaleYear
                    ,b.BKS_CUS_RecordID
                    ,SUM(b.BKS_BookAmt) As Amount
            From    Bookings As b With (Nolock)
            Where   Datepart(Year, b.BKS_BookDate) >= @LastSales
            Group By b.BKS_TerritoryCodes
                    ,Datepart(Year, b.BKS_BookDate)
                    ,b.BKS_CUS_RecordID
            ) As s
)

Select   sc.BKS_TerritoryCodes
        ,sc.SaleYear
        ,CUS_CorpName
        ,MAX(sc.Amount) as Total_Sales
From    Sales_CTE As sc With (Nolock)

join Customer on CUS_RecordID = BKS_CUS_RecordID

Where   sc.TopSales <= 10
Group By sc.BKS_TerritoryCodes
        ,SaleYear
        ,CUS_CorpName
Order By sc.SaleYear Desc
```

The issues I still have are: 1. The bookings amount appears to be only the largest sale to each of the customers, when it need to be the sum of all of the bookings. That way when the top 10 in each region are returned, it is the top ten in sales for the whole year. 2. Also, for some reason, I only get a full data set for 2012 and then 1 region for 2014. I know there is a full data set for each of the regions.

Comment: its really good to have some sample data.

Comment: Mihir, You bring up a good point. I added more details in the post.

Comment: have you tried my given below solution ?

Comment: Mihir,Below are the changes I made to adapt the solution to my needs. I added it as update 2 to my original post. The issues I still have are that the amount should be the sum of all of their bookings for each given year. Right now it looks like it just gets their biggest order. Also, for some reason, I only get a full data set for 2012 and then 1 region for 2014. I know there is a full data set for each of the regions.Can you help?

Comment: In above code sample, before taking max, apply sum by same grouping in inner query and then take max.

Comment: Mihir, I have made the updates your suggested in the edited post above. The biggest issue I have right now is that it should return all of the top 10 customers for each region for each of the 4 years. So if I have 10 regions, I would have 10x10x4 results or 400. Right now, I am only getting 100 results.  Any insight here? I appreciate all of the help so far!

Comment: I got it! By changing this row to `Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.BKS_TerritoryCodes, s.SaleYear Order By s.Amount Desc) As TopSales` I was able to make it work. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer for the solution looks like this (Thanks again to Mihir):

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @Today         Date
        ,@LastSales     Int

Select   @Today = Getdate()
        ---- Last 4 years including current year, if excluding current year then use -4
        ,@LastSales = Datepart(Year, Dateadd(Year, -4, @Today))


;With Sales_CTE As
(
Select   s.*
        ,Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.SalesRegion, s.SaleYear Order By s.Amount Desc) As TopSales
From    (
            Select   b.SalesRegion
                    ,Datepart(Year, b.BookingDate) As SaleYear
                    ,CUS_CorpName
                    ,SUM(b.DeliveryBooking) As Amount
            From    ettBookingsKPIDetails As b With (Nolock)
            join Customer on CUS_CustomerID = Customer
            Where   Datepart(Year, b.BookingDate) >= @LastSales 
            Group By b.SalesRegion
                    ,Datepart(Year, b.BookingDate)
                    ,CUS_CorpName
        ) As s
)

Select   sc.SalesRegion
        ,sc.SaleYear
        ,sc.CUS_CorpName
        ,sc.Amount as Total_Sales
From    Sales_CTE As sc With (Nolock)

Where   sc.TopSales <= 10 and SalesRegion is not NULL

Order By sc.SaleYear Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @Today         Date
        ,@LastSales     Int

Select   @Today = Getdate()
        ---- Last 4 year including current year, if excluding current year then use -4
        ,@LastSales = Datepart(Year, Dateadd(Year, -3, @Today))

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#Sales') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #Sales
End

Create Table #Sales
(
     SaleId         Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,Amount         Numeric(18,2) 
    ,SaleDate       Date
    ,Territory      Varchar(200)
    ,CustomerId     Int
)

Insert Into #Sales(Amount,SaleDate,Territory,CustomerId)
Values (18542,'2015-02-15','Andaman and Nicobar Islands',3)
        ,(1542,'2015-03-05','Andaman and Nicobar Islands',1)
        ,(11542,'2014-03-05','Chandigarh',1)
        ,(15542,'2011-11-05','Chandigarh',5)
        ,(6542,'2013-12-15','Andaman and Nicobar Islands',3)
        ,(4542,'2014-06-05','Andaman and Nicobar Islands',1)
        ,(8542,'2012-08-05','Chandigarh',1)
        ,(2642,'2015-10-05','Chandigarh',5)

;With Sales_CTE As
(
    Select   s.*
            ,Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.Territory Order By s.Territory,s.SaleYear,s.Amount Desc) As TopSales
    From    (
                Select   s.Territory
                        ,Datepart(Year, s.SaleDate) As SaleYear
                        ,s.CustomerId
                        ,Max(s.Amount) As Amount
                From    #Sales As s With (Nolock)
                Where   Datepart(Year, s.SaleDate) >= @LastSales
                Group By s.Territory
                        ,Datepart(Year, s.SaleDate)
                        ,s.CustomerId
            ) As s
)

Select   sc.Territory
        ,sc.SaleYear
        ,sc.CustomerId
        ,sc.Amount
From    Sales_CTE As sc With (Nolock)
Where   sc.TopSales <= 10
Order By sc.SaleYear Desc
```